# graph api returns empty data array when requested post_id/reactions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get all the reactions of a facebook post with `post_id/reactions` in Graph API. But the returned data array is always empty. I have generated the access token with all the user data permissions. I am attaching a screenshot of the scenario.

[image: post_id/reactions not working]

Does this problem has something to do with some more permission?

EDIT:
I also found out that this `post_id/reactions` is only showing the data of my reactions of a post. So, if I react on a post and do a graph api query for that post, it will show my information only. Does anybody know the reason/solution for this? Attaching the scenario.

[image: post_id/reactions not working properly]

EDIT 2:
I followed a youtube tutorial to do it like this. But apparently, it cannot be done (at least with this way!). It is mentioned in the documentation (screenshot attached).

[image]

If anybody can still provide me any other way to do this, please mention.

Comment: You can not get details about the individual users who reacted, you can only get the summary counts - but for those you need to explicitly _ask_ for the summary to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the reaction of the user if you have his access token. This with:

```
{post-id}/?fields=reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1)
```

[image]

The returned field "viewer_reaction" is the reaction of the user in the post.